# giving an JSON request in java?

Tags: java, javascript, json, google-apps

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ya29.1.AADtN_UXi1QH4TBqXBR_FxQLMEkkm1z329tou- 3C7RZWdRfkQEfQ471QV8jR8jU
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "name": {
  "familyName": "sel",
  "givenName": "abc"
 },
 "password": "Abcd!234",
 "primaryEmail": "abc@domain.com"
}
```

How to give the above JSON request using Java? And how to deal with the JSON response?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: try looking into GSON Library !!

Comment: I"d make a serializable class for the response and use GSON and use the httpclient stuff for the request use java.net.HttpUrlConnection or a URL and openConnection

Comment: Thank you so much people. But I'm very new to this topic, so can you people explain a bit deeper, please?